# How does Java handle precision across multiple types?

Tags: java, precision, primitive-types

In Java when I print something like this

```
System.out.println(1.0f*1l));
```

I get an output of

```
1.0
```

or with

```
System.out.println(((byte)1)*'A');
```

I get an output of

```
65
```

In both cases, one of the types is bigger than the other. Longs are 64-bits while floats are 32-bits, and bytes are 8-bits while chars are 16-bits. Despite this, Java outputs the result in the smaller type. Wouldn't this be considered a loss of precision?

Comment: This is covered in exhaustive detail in the Java Language Specification. There's an entire chapter [Conversions and Contexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html).

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java Language Specification provides a list of rules governing the type of result based on the types of operands.

In particular, section 4.2.4 says that

> If at least one of the operands to a binary operator is of floating-point type, then the operation is a floating-point operation, even if the other is integral.

which explains why `float` "wins" against a `long`.

Integer arithmetic is explained in section 5.6.2. Specifically, it says that

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> • If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>
> • Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
>
> • Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>
> • Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

That is why in your second example the result, 65, is of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Java widens type based on the range of possible values. This means `float` is considered wider than`long`.

Also integer operations which are not `long` are performed as `int`. 
A `byte * char` is an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about [Binary Numeric Promotion (JLS 5.6.2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) (emphasis mine):

> When an operator applies *binary numeric promotion* to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
>    - Otherwise, **if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`**.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
>    - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`**.

The expression `1.0f*1l` is a `float` and `long`, so the `long` is converted to a `float`.

The expression `((byte)1)*'A'` is a `byte` and a `char`, so they are both converted to `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers that spell out the rules in detail, I think it's also worth considering why it should be this way. Suppose you do

```
2.7F * 2L
```

The true mathematical answer to this multiplication is 5.4. Therefore if the answer were a `long`, it would have to be `5L` (5 is the closest integer to 5.4). Because of this kind of thing it makes much more sense for the result of multiplying a floating-point value by an integer to be a floating point value. I think there would be many more questions about this on Stack Overflow if the following line of code printed `5`.

```
System.out.println(2.7F * 2L);
```

In fact it prints `5.4`.

It also makes sense that all operations between integer types (except `long`) are done with `int`. After all, a `byte` is usually thought of as a small packet of data, and a `char` is usually thought of as a character. From these perspectives multiplying `byte` or `char` values isn't really meaningful. It makes much more sense to keep the rules simple and just do the operations with `int`.